# synchronous code execution

Tags: java, android

I am having some problem with execution of functions in Android Java. I have a fragment with webview, upon button on click, I will execute the export to pdf function in view model. If success, then I proceed to close the fragment with webview.

Here is the code where I call the export to pdf function:

```
@Click(R.id.buttonExport)
void buttonExportClicked(View v){
    SummaryViewModel summaryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SummaryViewModel.class);
    boolean exportSuccess = summaryViewModel.export(ResultFragment.this, webViewResult);

    if(exportSuccess == true) dismiss();
}
```

In my viewmodel:

```
private boolean exportSuccess;
public boolean export(ResultFragment context, WebView webViewResult) {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/PDFTest/");
    String fileName = "Summary.pdf";

    PdfView.createWebPrintJob(context.getActivity(), webViewResult, directory, fileName, new PdfView.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void success(String path) {
            PdfView.openPdfFile(context.getActivity(), context.getString(R.string.app_name), "Do you want to open the " + fileName + " file?", path);
            exportSuccess = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void failure() {
            exportSuccess = false;
        }
    });
    return exportSuccess;
}
```

For the export to pdf function, I am following [this guide](https://github.com/pramodkr123/ConvertWebViewToPdfDemo). The problem is, I managed to reach the openPdfFile, which means that I already set the exportSuccess to true, however, from my fragment whereby the export button is clicked, it always return false and therefore the fragment with webview is unable to dismissed.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have passed the context of the fragment **ResultFragment context** so you can use the context in the same method to dismiss the dialog like `context.dismiss();`.
The snippet attached by you seems to be okay , it should work if it is running in synchronous manner.

Answer (score 0):

it seems , your method is getting returned before the PdfView.createWebPrintJob () is finishing.

You can pass a callback in export(ResultFragment context, WebView webViewResult,ICallback callback);

```
public interface ICallback{
    void onSuccess();
    void onFailure();
}
```

call the respective methods in PdfView.createWebPrintJob(), In the implementation of callback you can dismiss the dialog.

Ankit